# Flow Sequence in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I want to create a chrome extension which can interpret the command given via keyboard.
The aim of this extension is that if the user presses ALT + A then display the tab id in the alert box

```
Manifest File :
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Toggle",
  "description": "This App ",
  "version": "1.0",

  "background": {
    "persistent": true,
    "scripts": ["TabBackGround.js"]
  },

  "commands":
    {
        "toggle" : 
        {
            "suggested_key": {
              "default": "Alt+A",
              "mac": "Command+Shift+Y"
            },
            "description" : "Toggle the tabs"
        }
    },

  "permissions": ["tabs", "background"],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "This App will help to toggle through tabs on which videos is running",
    "default_icon": "hello.png"
  }     
}
```

TabBackGround.js

```
var globalId;

chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
    if (command == "toggle") 
    {
        alert ("Command Resolved." );
        var queryGetTabs = chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(arrayOfTabs) {

            alert ("Function Executed." );

            var activeTab = arrayOfTabs[0];
            var activeTabId = arrayOfTabs[0].id; 
            globalId = activeTabId;
     });

        alert ("Pressed Toggle : " + globalId);
    }
});
```

Output : Command Resolved.
Pressed Toggle
Function Executed.
I want to understand what is the flow of execution in javascript. Shouldn't the Function exected statement come before Pressed toggle.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the Chrome API is asynchronous for performance/responsiveness reasons. What you're seeing is this:

```
/* Some code that will execute first */
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  /* Some code that will execute last */
}
/* Some code that will execute second */
```

Executing `chrome.tabs.query` will not do anything immediately (and will not return anything, by the way), but instead asks Chrome to query the tabs whenever it can and then execute the callback. That's why it's called "callback", by the way.

Other way to look at it: you're registering the callback as a handler for an event "work is done". Whenever it's actually done.

So your function will continue after scheduling this action, and cannot use any results of the callback function. If you need those in asynchronous code, you need to chain your calls:

```
/* Some code that will execute first */
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  /* Some code that will execute second */    
  chrome.someOtherApiFunction(function() {
    /* Some code that will execute last */
  });
}
```

Comment: is there a way we can make query call synchronous ?

Comment: In short, no. The call is not actually happening in JavaScript but rather in Chrome's native code, which, I suppose, runs out of sync with page's JS. If you want some better tools to work with asynchronous code, you may want to take a look at [Promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/). Though here it might be an overkill.

Comment: Ok thanks for your reply. I understood the difference between sync and async call ans made changes to the code accordingly. I am trying to display Tab Id and Tab URl of the current active tab.