# Chrome Extension - Alert statement changes the results

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, dom-events

I am trying to display Tab Id and Tab URL of the current active tab. However, if I comment all the alert statements (1, 2 and 3) I do not get the result as expected.

Example: If I comment out all alert statements then the first time I press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, I get null value in URL and 0 in ID field which means the variables are not initialized.

TabBackGround.js

```
var currentTabId = 0;
var currentTabURL = "null";

chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {

    alert ("1. Inside Listener"); //1
    chrome.tabs.query({active:true, currentWindow: true}, function(arrayOfTabs) {

        alert("2. Filtering Results");  //2
        currentTabURL = arrayOfTabs[0].url;
        currentTabId = arrayOfTabs[0].id; 
            
    });
    
    if (command == "toggle") 
    {
        alert ("3. Resolved Command"); //3
        alert ("TAB ID = " + currentTabId + "\n URL =  " + currentTabURL);
    }    
});
```

But, If I keep all the alert statements extension works fine.
What I don't understand is how is alert statement making difference  in the final result!

Manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Display Tab Information",
  "description": "Extension will display Tab Id and Tab URL in an alert box",
  "version": "1.0",
  
  "background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["TabBackGround.js"]
  },
  
  "commands":
    {
        "toggle" : 
        {
            "suggested_key": {
              "default": "Alt+A",
              "mac": "Command+Shift+Y"
            },
            "description" : "Display Id and URL of the current open/active tab."
        }
    },
  
  "permissions": ["tabs", "background"],
   
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "This App will display Tab Id and Tab URL when user issues the command.",
    "default_icon": "hello.png"
  }     
}
```

Another point to note is

```
var currentTabId = 0;
var currentTabURL = "null";

chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {

    //alert ("1. Inside Listener");
    chrome.tabs.query({active:true, currentWindow: true}, function(arrayOfTabs) {

        alert("2. Filtering Results");
        currentTabURL = arrayOfTabs[0].url;
        currentTabId = arrayOfTabs[0].id; 

    });

    if (command == "toggle") 
    {
        alert ("3. Resolved Command" + "TAB ID = " + currentTabId + "\n URL =  " + currentTabURL);
        alert ("4. Check when does this get executed" + "TAB ID = " + currentTabId + "\n URL =  " + currentTabURL);
        alert ("TAB ID = " + currentTabId + "\n URL =  " + currentTabURL);
    }    
});
```

Found that Execution path was alert 3 (Current Id = 0 and CurrentURL = null) then alert 2 got executed and then alert 4 with the correct value of Current Id and Current URL.

Comment: Because it doesn't. It's a different problem. Still same as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26096646/flow-sequence-in-chrome-extension

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't get your reply  !! Can you please elaborate more ?

Comment: I got it.. It is not about the other alert statments but just the alert 3 which when executed gives the chance to CurrentTabURL and CurrentTabIf to get intialized. Is there a work around for the same  rather than using alert statement ?

Comment: Deleted and Updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Okay, that's an interesting question now. I retract my duplicate vote.

Consider this code:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  alert("C"); // Should be next in queue for execution
}, 0);
alert("A");
alert("B");
```

As expected, it outputs the sequence A,B,C, as the asynchronously-executed function only executes after the main execution thread returns. `alert("A")` **blocks the thread**, but the function does not return yet, so the next executed statement is `alert("B")`.

**However, Chrome APIs hijack execution while the browser is blocked on `alert`!**

Consider (the following snippets must be run in the context of a background page of a chrome extension):

```js
chrome.tabs.query({}, function() { 
  alert("C"); // Should be in queue for execution after results are available?..
});
alert("A");
alert("B");
```

The first line calls a native code operation in Chrome and registers a handler for results.

The second line blocks the execution; normally, this would normally mean that everything is stopped. **But instead at this point Chrome executes the `query` callback!**

So, the end result is the sequence A,C,B.

It's possible to observe that this out-of-queue execution does not have its own separate queue:

```
chrome.tabs.query({}, function() {
  setTimeout( function(){
    alert("C");
  }, 0);
});
alert("A");
alert("B");
```

Will give the expected A,B,C sequence. The handler is called while the first alert is displayed, and pushes `alert(C)` in the main "execution queue". Additional testing also shows that `alert("A")` does not actually return until the handler finishes execution.

---

**This is *weird*.** I wonder what other functions except `alert`, `confirm` and `prompt` exhibit this behavior, and if it's possible to reproduce it outside Chrome APIs.

I also wonder if it's intentional, and what is the rationale if it is. Some kind of (undocumented?) deadlock prevention?

---

As for a workaround - do not use `alert()` and friends for debugging. `console.log()` does not block and will work as expected.

To see the background page's console, you can go to `chrome://extensions/`; to see the popup's console, right-click the button and select "Inspect popup".

Comment: Tried console.log() and dummy statement var x = 10 but nothing works  ! !

Comment: @DeepikaAnand I am _deeply_ confused by what you said there.